# When testing, 'python setup.py test' is the only way to test in Python Package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tdd, scaffolding

There is a problem that I have in Python package structure.

Here is what I did in Mac OSX and Python 3.4:

```
1. mkdir MyProject
2. cd MyProject
3. virtualenv --python=python3.4 venv
4. . venv/bin/activate
5. pip install pytest pyscaffold
6. putup MyProject
```

Then, the directory structure would look like this :

```
MyProject/
   MyProject/
      docs/
      myproject/
      tests/
      requirements.txt
      setup.py
      .
      .
   venv/
```

And I added `apple.py` in `myproject` and `test_apple.py` in `tests`.

Then, structure would be like this :

```
MyProject/
   MyProject/
      docs/
      myproject/
         apple.py
      tests/
         test_apple.py
      requirements.txt
      setup.py
      .
      .
   venv/
```

**apple.py**

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)

print("start apple")

def get_apple():
    print("apple!!")
    return 5
```

When I run `apple.py` by typing `python apple.py` in `myproject` directory, it prints :

```
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject/myproject
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python34.zip
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
start apple
```

As you can see above, `sys.path` include     `/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject/myproject`

So, I made a `test_apple.py` like this:

**test_apple.py**

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)

from myproject.apple import get_apple

def test_apple():
    assert 5 == get_apple()
```

When I ran this code by typing `py.test -s test_apple.py`, 
 
(`-s` option is for showing the result of `print` statement in the code)

```
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject/tests
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python34.zip
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin
/Users/Chois/Desktop/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_apple.py", line 5, in <module>
    from myproject.apple import get_apple
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
```

However, when I run test by typing `python setup.py test`, it runs without errors! !!

What I want to know here is how I can run a specific test module using `py.test -s test_xxxx.py` instead of **ALL** test modules by `python setup.py test`.

Need your helps, thanks.

Comment: Did you try to install your package in development mode?

pip install -e path/to/MyProject

Comment: @serhiy.h Cool! You save me :) Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [Good Integration Practices](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html).

> make sure that “mypkg” is importable, for example by typing once:
>
> `pip install -e .   # install package using setup.py in editable mode`